# Bot Framework web chat bot adding Typing Indicator for every message using NODE JS?

Tags: node.js, azure, session, botframework, chatbot

Issue : 
how to show typing acitivity for every user activity ?

Platform : node js 101.5
Framework : Bor Framework 4.5

Comment: Are you trying to display a typing indicator while the user is typing, when the bot is typing, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Web Chat's `sendTyping` prop to `true` and then echo the typing events sent to bot back to the conversation.

#### Web Chat

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
    directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
    sendTyping: true
  },
  document.getElementById('webchat')
);
```

#### BotFramework SDK v4 (Node)

```
this.onUnrecognizedActivityType(async context => {
  const { activity: { type } } = context;

  if (type === ActivityTypes.Typing) {
    await context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
  }
});
```

#### Screen Capture

[image]

Currently you have to capture typing events from the user in the `onUnrecognizedActivityType` message handler; however, there is an open GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/1140) to add an `onTyping` event handler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the out of the box webchat instead of via DirectLine?

Comment: This is using Web Chat out of the box.

Comment: Bot onUnrecognizedActivityType function works fine on Azure Server but some function not working  localhost deployment

Comment: Localhost  onUnrecognizedActivityType not fired . I need your support for further chatbot developement  , Whatsapp me : +91 9786 25 26 24